# Using fopen() to read from a file not working correctly

Tags: c, file, io

I'm new to C and learning how to read and write to files for an assignment. Can someone please explain to me why the function below sometimes reads the file correctly and sometimes it spouts out gibberish? I believe it has to do with the fileName. However, I printed out the file name and it holds the correct string so I don't know why it works sometimes and other times it does not (most of the time it doesn't work).

UPDATED: The code to properly test if the the file opened and built the path name from scratch to ensure I was passing a string literal. Output is sometimes correct and sometimes nonsense

```
void playGame(struct Room *HoldRooms[], char dirName[], char fileName[], int 
roomStart)
{
//file and path name

   char filePathName[100]; 
   char tempString[100]; 
   char string[MAX_STRING_LENGTH];
   char field1[MAX_STRING_LENGTH];
   char field2[MAX_STRING_LENGTH];
   char field3[MAX_STRING_LENGTH];

   filePathName[0] = 0;
   char c;
   strcpy(filePathName, dirName); 
   strcat(filePathName, "/");
   strcat(filePathName, "room");
   sprintf(tempString, "%d",roomStart);
   strcat(filePathName,tempString);

   //All lines contain three fields we will only need the third
   FILE *fp = fopen(filePathName, "r");
   chmod(filePathName,  S_IRUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH);


   printf("The file is %s \n", filePathName);

   if (fp == NULL)  //If the file does not open
   {
    //fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s\n", fileName);
    //perror("in main");
    printf("Could not open file\n" );
    exit(1);
   }
  else
  {
    printf("Opened file %s \n", filePathName);
    //fprintf(fp, "BLAH BLAH BLAH!");
    fscanf(fp, "%s %s %s", field1, field2, field3);
    printf("1: %s 2: %s 3: %s", field1, field2, field3);
  }


fclose(fp);  //close the file
```

}

Comment: `if (fp < 0)` change to `if (fp == NULL)` though that might be the full solution. Have a read of the man page for `fopen`.

Comment: Does the file contain the format you're trying to read which is "string string string"

Comment: Yeah it's just a test file that says ROOM NAME: Cockpit

Answer (score 0):

This test

```
if (fp < 0) //If the file does not open
```

is not the correct way to test if the file was opened. If `fopen` cannot open the file it returns `NULL` and this is what you must check.

```
if (fp == NULL) //If the file does not open
```

The way you have it, a `NULL` value will pass your check, whereas a "negative" file pointer might be valid, but fail your check. Although you mentioned one particular file content, you also referred to "files" and I suspect you meant to say that some file names work and some do not: rather than one single file sometimes producing gibberish.

Comment: I modified my test to be fp == NULL and it  says the file is opened but I'm getting nonsense from the file. I checked the directory I that is storing the files and they exist. The file does change with each run of the program (in a previous part of the code) the file to be opened is randomly selected.

Comment: @user2466886 you have not checked the return value from `chmod` nor from `fscanf` these are basic and essential safeguards. You now checked the result of `fopen` correctly, but in the wrong place: it should be immediately after attempting to open the file.

Comment: I changed my code and it's still throwing out junk. Can you not pass a variable as the name of file?